# errors in stacks in ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm not familiar at ROS errors,,
firstly , i installed Roboearth Stack using these four steps :

**http://www.ros.org/wiki/roboearth**

the result of that : I have the roboearth stack in Home/ros

i made a connection between this and ROS
by opening bashrc file
and typed "**export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks:/home/ros**"

and saved

i begin to run re_comm package in roboearth stack but itthrow an error

```
salma@salma-G31M-S2L:~$ rosrun re_comm run
[rospack] Error: stack/package re_comm not found
```

i don't know why ???
re_comm not in /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
but in /home/ros/roboearth

why not found ??

and this is the result of rosmake roboearth now

```
salma@salma-G31M-S2L:~$ rosmake roboearth
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                 
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['roboearth']                               
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/salma/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121111-201259
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['roboearth'] to:
[]                                  
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['roboearth']
[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47981/errors-in-stacks-in-ros/) by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2012-11-11

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2012-11-12**:
@tbh ???? any help here ?

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2012-11-12**:
@Lorenz ???? any help here ?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-12**:
Please do not add my name just to enforce a notification email. I see your question and I will answer it if I know the answer and if I have time. Be aware that I'm giving support here in my free time and voluntarily.

**Comment by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on 2012-11-12**:
Are you sure /home/ros is the correct directory for roboearth?  In FHS (Filesystem Hierarchy Standard), the home directory ~/. is the same as /home/username/.   /home/. is a different place. Since your username is salma, I'd guess that you should use /home/salma/ros instead of /home/ros

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2012-11-12**:
lorenz @

i didn't mean it :S ,, just i was reading ROS EnvironmentVariables and it was last updates by u !! so i mentioned u ,,,,, Not to enforce a notification email !! ,, thanks by the way :)

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2012-11-12**:
@tbh
Ok I will try it and tell you the result
,, yesterday i decided to uninstall ROS and install it again after no one answered me ,,
i 'm installing it again and 'll retry :)
thanks very much

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2012-11-13**:
@tbh
it's okey it solved ,, thanks very much

**Comment by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on 2012-11-13**:
Great! Be sure and post the answer or accept the right one for others who might have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the home directory **~/.** is the same as **/home/username/.**
you should use **/home/username/ros** instead of **/home/ros**

---

Originally posted by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) with karma: 464 on 2012-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2